Distinctions and usage of "that"
I've found Is it grammatically acceptable to start a sentence with "That that..."? but it isn't quite what I'm looking for.

To get paid for what you love, that is the meaning of success.


He got paid for what he loved doing. That is the meaning of success.

What is the distinction here between the usage of that, in terms of the main clause?
Is that is the meaning of success a fragment without the preceding sentence?
I understand that refers to something clear in the first sentence, but should it be written like A, rather than splitting up?

No time for an answer right now, but https://www.aresearchguide.com/repeated-subjects-in-a-sentence.html might help explain "A"

Those usages are exactly the same.
"B." is just "A" broken into two short sentences. It is better writing because of clarity.
